# G-groups homomorphism regarding the subgroup fixed by G

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence, group-cohomology

I suspect there is a very simple argument for this question but I cannot get any further in this statement.

I am currently studying the connecting homomorphism between $H_0$ and $H_1$ (of group cohomology) and I need the following fact (prove or disprove)

Let $G$ be a group and $B$ and $C$ being $G$-group (groups with group action by $G$, the group operation is compatible with the group action).
Let $f:B\rightarrow C$ be a homomorphism.  Prove or disprove that $\ker f$ (which is in $B$) is a subset of $B^G$.  In other words, $\forall g\in G,k\in\ker f,g\cdot k=k$. (I mean $g$ acting on $k$ is $k$ itself, or $k$ is fixed by any $g\in G$)

I can provide more proof of work I have done (like I have reduced the problem of "well-definedness of connecting homomorphism" to this specific question.  If the statement above is not generally true, then probably my deduction goes wrong.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that for any morphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules $f:B\rightarrow C$, we have $\ker f\subset B^G$ ? This certainly doesn't work if $C=0$ and $B$ is not trivial.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module is exactly $G$-groups.  Like my example in my mind is $G=\{\pm 1\}$ acting by multiplication, on groups $B=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $C=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  I observe that the kernel is fixed by $G$ and I suspect there is something relevant to this observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that $Ker f$ is stable by $G$ equivalently, for every $x\in B$, $g\in G$, $f(x)=1$ implies that $f(g.x)=g.f(x)=g.1=1$. But you do not have necessarily $g.x=x$ if $x\in Ker f$, consider the example: $G=G$ endowed with the adjoint action, $g.g'=gg'g^{-1}$, $C=\{1\}$ the trivial group endowed with the trivial action of $G$, and $f:G\rightarrow \{1\}$, $ker f=G$, but $G\neq G^G$ if $G$ is not commutative.